# Getting MAC address in Android 6.0

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address

I'm developing an app that gets the MAC address of the device, but since Android 6.0 my code doesn't work, giving me an incorrect value.

Here's my code...

```
public String ObtenMAC()
{
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();

    return(info.getMacAddress().toUpperCase());
}
```

Instead of the real MAC address, it returns an strange code: `02:00:00:00:00:00`.

Comment: Did you made sure that you checked for the `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` before getting the MAC-Address? In M it won't work if you only ask for it in the Manifest you have to implemet it in rumtime like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8lUdPVSzDk&index=3&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-lJo_RGGXL2Psr8vVCTWjM

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have that permission in my Manifest, but when I go to check it programatically as shown in the video, Android Studio doesn't recognize "checkSelfPermission", I don't know if could be because I`m targeting API 21 Lollipop and hasn't installed API 23 Marshmallow.

Comment: Before you call checkSelfPermission you should check if the SDK Version is lass than API 23 Marshmallow like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically

Comment: It is always good to have the newest Android API version at the target level

Comment: Please check this solution, it works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329733/how-to-get-the-missing-wifi-mac-address-on-android-m-preview

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please refer to [Android 6.0 Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.

Comment: I have those permissions on my app and still doesn't work.

Comment: @Hrodger, you can't get your own MACs even having those permissions. Read carefully. It is said that you can get **other devices MACs** having those permissions, but not yourth

Comment: So there is no way to do it?

Comment: You can  still get mac address through java.net.NetworkInterface  apparently. Yes, I'm of very high opinion about Google developers abilities;).

Answer (score 27):

Use below code to get Mac address in Android 6.0

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: The above answer was taken from this blog post: http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically

Comment: This answer got a bug where a byte that in hex form got a single digit, will not appear with a "0" before it.  The append to res1 should be changed to res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));

Comment: Works in Android 7 as well.

Comment: WiFi MAC address is not always the same as Bluetooth interface. On my phone only first 3 octaves matches (which btw inform about vendor).

Answer (score 15):

I didn't get the above answer to work, but stumbled upon another answer.

Here is a complete and simple method on getting the IPv6 address and then getting the mac address from it.

[How to get Wi-Fi Mac address in Android Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103798/how-to-get-wi-fi-mac-address-in-android-marshmallow)

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

Tested it already and it works. Many thanks to Rob Anderson!

Comment: Thanks, as stated elsewhere this needs <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to work.

Answer (score 11):

this is the complete 2 ways code of getting it successfully on Marshmallow , just copy past this and it will work !

```
//Android 6.0 : Access to mac address from WifiManager forbidden
    private static final String marshmallowMacAddress = "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    private static final String fileAddressMac = "/sys/class/net/wlan0/address";    

public static String recupAdresseMAC(WifiManager wifiMan) {
        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();

        if(wifiInf.getMacAddress().equals(marshmallowMacAddress)){
            String ret = null;
            try {
                ret= getAdressMacByInterface();
                if (ret != null){
                    return ret;
                } else {
                    ret = getAddressMacByFile(wifiMan);
                    return ret;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("MobileAccess", "Erreur lecture propriete Adresse MAC");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MobileAcces", "Erreur lecture propriete Adresse MAC ");
            }
        } else{
            return wifiInf.getMacAddress();
        }
        return marshmallowMacAddress;
    }

private static String getAdressMacByInterface(){
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
                if (nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) {
                    byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                    if (macBytes == null) {
                        return "";
                    }

                    StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                    for (byte b : macBytes) {
                        res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
                    }

                    if (res1.length() > 0) {
                        res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                    }
                    return res1.toString();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MobileAcces", "Erreur lecture propriete Adresse MAC ");
        }
        return null;
    }

private static String getAddressMacByFile(WifiManager wifiMan) throws Exception {
        String ret;
        int wifiState = wifiMan.getWifiState();

        wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(true);
        File fl = new File(fileAddressMac);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    while((ch = fin.read()) != -1){
        builder.append((char)ch);
    }

    ret = builder.toString();
    fin.close();

        boolean enabled = WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED == wifiState;
        wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
        return ret;
    }
```

manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

- **Summary : this code will try to get the MAC address first by Interface and if its failed it get it by file system.**
- **Note:for file System way, you need to enable WIFI to access the file.**

thnx to Sam's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39288868/3818437

Answer (score 6):

You can get the MAC address from the IPv6 local address. E.g., the IPv6 address "fe80::1034:56ff:fe78:9abc" corresponds to the MAC address "12-34-56-78-9a-bc". See the code below. Getting the WiFi IPv6 address only requires android.permission.INTERNET.

See the Wikipedia page [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses), particularly the note about "local addresses" fe80::/64 and the section about "Modified EUI-64".

```
/**
 * Gets an EUI-48 MAC address from an IPv6 link-local address.
 * E.g., the IPv6 address "fe80::1034:56ff:fe78:9abc"
 * corresponds to the MAC address "12-34-56-78-9a-bc".
 * <p/>
 * See the note about "local addresses" fe80::/64 and the section about "Modified EUI-64" in
 * the Wikipedia article "IPv6 address" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address
 *
 * @param ipv6 An Inet6Address object.
 * @return The EUI-48 MAC address as a byte array, null on error.
 */
private static byte[] getMacAddressFromIpv6(final Inet6Address ipv6)
{
    byte[] eui48mac = null;

    if (ipv6 != null) {
        /*
         * Make sure that this is an fe80::/64 link-local address.
         */
        final byte[] ipv6Bytes = ipv6.getAddress();
        if ((ipv6Bytes != null) &&
                (ipv6Bytes.length == 16) &&
                (ipv6Bytes[0] == (byte) 0xfe) &&
                (ipv6Bytes[1] == (byte) 0x80) &&
                (ipv6Bytes[11] == (byte) 0xff) &&
                (ipv6Bytes[12] == (byte) 0xfe)) {
            /*
             * Allocate a byte array for storing the EUI-48 MAC address, then fill it
             * from the appropriate bytes of the IPv6 address. Invert the 7th bit
             * of the first byte and discard the "ff:fe" portion of the modified
             * EUI-64 MAC address.
             */
            eui48mac = new byte[6];
            eui48mac[0] = (byte) (ipv6Bytes[8] ^ 0x2);
            eui48mac[1] = ipv6Bytes[9];
            eui48mac[2] = ipv6Bytes[10];
            eui48mac[3] = ipv6Bytes[13];
            eui48mac[4] = ipv6Bytes[14];
            eui48mac[5] = ipv6Bytes[15];
        }
    }

    return eui48mac;
}
```

Comment: It seems that Mac Address is randomized even you can catch it!
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Comment: The WifiManager API was changed in Android 6.0 to return a fake MAC address. But you can still get the IPv6 link local address for the Wi-Fi network and then extract the MAC address as above. This works on every device I have tried.

Comment: Hi @Yojimbo, will this code return the MAC address of the router, or that of the device?

Comment: This is the WiFi MAC address of the device. You may be able to get the MAC of the WiFi access point using WiFiManager.getScanResults(). For a WAP, the BSSID equals the MAC address.

Comment: You can enumerate the network interfaces using [NetworkInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html). See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010903/network-interface-names-for-android-devices) for an example. Use the Java instanceof operator to determine which IP addresses are [Inet6Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html)

Answer (score 5):

I try to get mac address with 2 methods, first by Interface and if its failed, i get it by file system, but you need to enable wifi to access the file.

```
//Android 6.0 : Access to mac address from WifiManager forbidden
    private static final String marshmallowMacAddress = "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    private static final String fileAddressMac = "/sys/class/net/wlan0/address";    

public static String recupAdresseMAC(WifiManager wifiMan) {
        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();

        if(wifiInf.getMacAddress().equals(marshmallowMacAddress)){
            String ret = null;
            try {
                ret= getAdressMacByInterface();
                if (ret != null){
                    return ret;
                } else {
                    ret = getAddressMacByFile(wifiMan);
                    return ret;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("MobileAccess", "Erreur lecture propriete Adresse MAC");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MobileAcces", "Erreur lecture propriete Adresse MAC ");
            }
        } else{
            return wifiInf.getMacAddress();
        }
        return marshmallowMacAddress;
    }

private static String getAdressMacByInterface(){
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
                if (nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) {
                    byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                    if (macBytes == null) {
                        return "";
                    }

                    StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                    for (byte b : macBytes) {
                        res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
                    }

                    if (res1.length() > 0) {
                        res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                    }
                    return res1.toString();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MobileAcces", "Erreur lecture propriete Adresse MAC ");
        }
        return null;
    }

private static String getAddressMacByFile(WifiManager wifiMan) throws Exception {
        String ret;
        int wifiState = wifiMan.getWifiState();

        wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(true);
        File fl = new File(fileAddressMac);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
        ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
        fin.close();

        boolean enabled = WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED == wifiState;
        wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
        return ret;
    }
```

Add this line to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I recommend you to persist your mac address in your preferences like here

```
mac = activity.getSharedPreferences("MAC_ADDRESS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("MAC_ADDRESS", "");
                if(mac == null || mac.equals("")){
                    WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    mac = MobileAccess.recupAdresseMAC(wifiMan);
                    if(mac != null && !mac.equals("")){
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = activity.getSharedPreferences("MAC_ADDRESS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("MAC_ADDRESS", mac).commit();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 5):

**Its Perfectly Fine**

```
package com.keshav.fetchmacaddress;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("keshav","getMacAddr -> " +getMacAddr());
    }

    public static String getMacAddr() {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
                if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

                byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                if (macBytes == null) {
                    return "";
                }

                StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : macBytes) {
                    res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                }

                if (res1.length() > 0) {
                    res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                }
                return res1.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome zums for like me

Comment: With Android 12 it wont't work. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#mac-address

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add Internet user permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then you can find the mac over the NetworkInterfaces API.

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

Comment: The above answer was taken from this blog post: http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The answers are mostly correct, but keep care, that there is a change in android 7.  You will need to use the

**DevicePolicyManager** and the Method **getWifiMacAddress**. The official docs has a typo, which means that you shouldnt copy/paste it from there.

```
DevicePolicyManager.getWifiMacAddress()
```

Refs: 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html

[Get Device mac adress in Android Nougat and O programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338359/get-device-mac-adress-in-android-nougat-and-o-programmatically/43339101?noredirect=1#comment73742692_43339101)

Answer (score 1):

Use **wifiInfo.getBSSID()** to get Mac Address of AccessPoint instead of **getMacAddress** method.

Comment: Only provides the mac address of the device your connected to like a wifi router. Not the device itself

Answer (score 0):

This is a more kotlin way to get Mac Address

```
fun getMacAddress(): String =
        NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList()
                .firstOrNull { it.name.equals("wlan0", ignoreCase = true) }?.let {
                    it.hardwareAddress?.let { macBytes ->
                        StringBuilder().apply {
                            for (b in macBytes) {
                                append(String.format("%02X:", b))
                            }
                            if (isNotEmpty()) {
                                deleteCharAt(lastIndex)
                            }
                        }
                    }.toString()
                } ?: "02:00:00:00:00:00"
```