# get MAC address in android 6

Tags: android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-bluetooth

I've refer https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id
and 
[Getting MAC address in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159224/getting-mac-address-in-android-6-0).
It seems to be unable to get MAC address in android 6.

Without `WifiInfo.getMacAddress()` and the `BluetoothAdapter.getAddress()` can we have an other way to get MAC address programmatically of local device.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the file `/sys/class/net/wlan0/address`. The MAC address will be in the usual colon deliminated form. Works on my unrooted Nexus 6P running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: it does not work on non-rooted Xiaomi Redmi 4 Pro