# How do I get the Mac Address for and Android Device using 6.0 or higher in c#?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mac-address

I have found a few examples using Java, however I am having trouble constructing the method to c#. Can anyone please post a straightforward c# example that gets the Mac Address of my device, FOR Marshmallow (6.0). I understand that there are other methods of obtaining a unique Id, I am not really interested in having to import components at this time. I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015.

I have these permissions active:

ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
 INTERNET
 READ_PHONE_STATE

The only codes I have tried are the simple methods used for below android version 6.0. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: *I do not believe this to be a duplicate as I requested for a c# version of the code specifically*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting MAC address in Android 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159224/getting-mac-address-in-android-6-0)

Comment: Well I noticed that someone was able to achieve this using Java: [link](http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically) Just need this code for c# if anyone can help.

Comment: I've tried that code before, it *might* work in a Cyanogen build as that is what he tested on, but I have not gotten it to work on a ASOP production build/release. The mac returned is always `null`.

Comment: @DaWiseguy I wasn't aware of the alternative way to get the address. I decided to try it and it sure seems to work. I updated my answer to contain a small code sample that works for Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck. Starting from version 6.0, Android restricts the access to the MAC address. If you try to query the MAC address of your current device, you'll get a constant value of `02:00:00:00:00:00`

You can still access MAC addresses of the nearby devices, as is stated in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id):

> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions:

**Edit:** While the official way of getting the MAC address is not supported, it sure seems to be possible by taking a little detour. I post here a minimal example that just goes through all network interfaces and outputs the MAC addresses to the console if there's one:

```
// NetworkInterface is from Java.Net namespace, not System.Net
var all = Collections.List(NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces);

foreach (var interface in all)
{
    var macBytes = (interface as NetworkInterface).GetHardwareAddress();

    if (macBytes == null) continue;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var b in macBytes)
    {
        sb.Append((b & 0xFF).ToString("X2") + ":");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().Remove(sb.Length - 1));
}
```

To use this in a real world scenario requires some null reference checking and other modifications, but it works.

Comment: Thanks hankide! What clean code too!! You just saved me at work.

Comment: @DaWiseguy That's great to hear! Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you feel like it solved the problem, so others know the solution works.

Comment: unfortunately I am new to the site, so my reputation is at 6, I need 15 before I can mark the answer. Will come back and do that for sure when I reach 15.