# How to add the reference for System.Management in VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, system.management

How to add the reference for `System.Management` in VSCode? It always shows the error:

> "The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the
> namespace 'System'"

I've right clicked on `System.Management` and there is no option of any reference management. Really don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: can you share more details about the code?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/ - the package is for Windows, what are you planning to do with it on MacOS?

Comment: I'm trying to get client's MAC Adress by  ManagementClass,and my developing device is Mac, because my app will run on ios&android.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are developing Xamarin application. `System.Management` is Windows only namespace/package, you'll need platform specific way of getting the MAC address. Without more details it's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to accomplish but you could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885747/1286216

Also, be aware that newer Android devices randomize MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CLI in your project directory to add dependencies in VS Code.
Here is the link from NuGET for System.Management :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/

Should be something like that :

```
 dotnet add package System.Management --version 6.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly select the `Project` in the top left corner.

[image]

Then right click the project in solution explorer then click `Reference` and `Add`.

[image]

Here within the Reference manager dialogue box you can choose the `System.(Whatever you want)`.

Comment: The question clearly states VS Code - why do you answer with how to do it in VS? Different programs, different UIs, different ways of doing things.

Comment: Yup ,it's just quite different,but still thx for answer me at first time.