# Xamarin forms: How to get MAC Adress Wifi

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the MAC Adress WIFI of the device I am logging in through code but could not do it.

We have given devices to workers in the warehouse, but they kept swapping and losing devices, so we would like to make sure who has which device and know who used a device last. Easiest solution seemed to find out the wifi mac adress on connection, but I cannot figure a way to get the mac adress.

I followed [this older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503429/how-to-get-mac-address-of-a-client-device-in-xamarin-forms) script and while I get what looks like an adress, it's not the same I get from opening the phone's settings.

All devices are android and we have no intention of installing it on iOS.

Comment: On which android version is your app running? since android 10 you cannot get the WiFi MAC address or any non-restable device identifiers unless your app is the device owner or it is a system app. [https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)

Comment: @kipo Android 10 and Android 13. So I guess it's simply impossible. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, starting from `Android 6.0`, Android restrains the access to the MAC address. See [Android 6.0 Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id:%7E:text=of%20your%20choice.-,Access%20to%20Hardware%20Identifier,-To%20provide%20users)