# get wifi mac on Android 6.0

Tags: java, android

I have an application that uses the MAC address to register. As everyone knows as of android 6.0 you can no longer use the old method to do this. My problem is it doesn't appear to be a straight forward get MAC address. Hoping someone can help suggest a way to get this working on android 6.0+

my code is as follows;

```
public void getMacAddress()
{
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
    Log.e("address", "mac address:" + macAddress);
    pref = getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_APPDATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit=pref.edit();

    if(macAddress!=null)
        edit.putString(Constant.P_DEVICEID, macAddress);
//  else
//      Toast.makeText(this," WiFi MAC address not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if( tm.getDeviceId()== null)
    {
        //edit.putBoolean(Constant.P_IS_TABLET, true);
        //Toast.makeText(Activity_Audio.this, "Tablet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        //Toast.makeText(Activity_Audio.this, "Not Tablet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: I believe getting the mac address is deprecated in Android 6+. Instead the function always returns 00:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: You should use getHardwareAddress() from NetworkInterface to get it.

Comment: and chance you could give me some idea what i need to do? im a NOOB.. :/

Comment: Loop on NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() and call  getHardwareAddress() on your wifi interface. Use getName() and check "wlan0".There is good chance that wlan0 is your wifi interface. Otherwise you must find his pretty name.

Comment: and chance you can email me? aiche@mt2015.com

Comment: I think you can go : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39144299/1366052

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys..