# Get Device mac adress in Android Nougat and O programmatically

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-settings, android-8.0-oreo

I have an application, which required device mac address. I'm getting mac address in Marshmallow and below easily but problem with android nougat and O. So how to find mac.

Comment: Is this finding mac address programmatically or manually ?

Comment: programmatically

Comment: why down vote ?

Answer (score 3):

Changed since 6.0 and later: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this
>   release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local
>   hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The
>   WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods
>   now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via
>   Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.

Behavior Changes in 7.0:

> Device owners can access device identifiers. A Device owner can access
>   the Wi-Fi MAC address of a device, using
>   DevicePolicyManagewr.getWifiMacAddress(). If Wi-Fi has never been
>   enabled on the device, this method returns a value of null.

Comment: i can find mac in 6 Marshmallow but not 7N.

Comment: Modified my answer. Now it should be solved. Use DevicePolicyManager (yes, above is DevicePolicyManagewr with W). There is a typo in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

After one hour,I just solved the Problem.....

```
DeviceAdminReceiver admin = new DeviceAdminReceiver();
DevicePolicyManager devicepolicymanager = admin.getManager(getApplicationContext());
ComponentName name1 = admin.getWho(getApplicationContext());
if (devicepolicymanager.isAdminActive(name1)){
            String mac_address = devicepolicymanager.getWifiMacAddress(name1);
            Log.e("macAddress",""+mac_address);
}
```

References :

1) Android for Work : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html

2) DevicePolicyManger : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getWifiMacAddress(android.content.ComponentName)

3) DeviceAdminReceiver:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#getWho(android.content.Context)

Happy Coding....

Comment: If "isAdminActive" is false, what does this mean ?

Comment: This solution is not working since isAdminActive is returning false